# File upload not going as post

Tags: php, html

I've got dozens of these working on a project but for some reason this does not seem to be working.

This is my HTML:

```
    <form action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="2">
    <p>Name:<br><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"  required></p>
    <p>Email:<br><input type="email" name="Email" id="Email"  required></p>
    <p>Image:<br><input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" size="1000000" required></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </form>
```

On the next page if I var_dump the POST values the file is not there. However when I var_dump the FILES variable it's all there and in the temp directory...etc. If I take the enctype off then the name of the file comes through as a value.

I'm really stuck on this now have I missed something painfully obvious?

I've so far done this:

1. Checked the .ini file to make sure uplaods are allowed
2. var_dump on both POST and FILES (not showing on POST but showing on FILES)
3. Checked the temporary directory is storing the file and it is
4. Triple and Quadruple checked for grammar error...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File upload never go as $_POST. It always comes under $_FILES

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: **FACE PALM** thank you - I had to run that POST variables through a foreach loop and hadn't even thought of that. Appreciate the help!